# Why is there paternal, for fatherly, fraternal, for brotherly, but no similar word for sons?

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology

If paternal is "relating to someone's parents", and fraternal "relating to someone's brothers", is there, or why isn't there, a word for "relating to someone's sons", i.e: sunternal 
Sentence example: "sunternal love"

Comment: I thought paternal was "relating to someone's _father_" and maternal was "relating to someone's _mother_".  As far as I know, there is no gender neutral term (yet)

Comment: @MichaelJ. the gender neutral term could be "parental"

Answer (score 165, accepted):

There is ***[filial](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/filial)***, from Latin *filius* "son" and *filia* "daughter". So *filial love* should work in most contexts.

Comment: You only got here first because I had to go to the grocer. :)

Comment: @tchrist♦: How grocerly of you.

Comment: Only thing is that there is no distinction if it is sons or daughters if is of importance.

Comment: I'll have to file this away for the next time I meet somebody claiming that the English language is intrinsically sexist! (Although we do have "daughterly", but no such word I can think of for a son -- not sure what that implies, apart from the expected lack of regulatity in English).

Comment: @nigel222: [Sonly](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sonly) does actually exist. But I do agree that's it's not really in common usage. According to the link, its usage has essentially tanked since the 1780s.

Comment: @tchrist very mercatorial

Comment: For what it's worth, _filial piety_ is a common term in anthropology and cultural studies.

Comment: @Cerberus If you wanted a worse pun: How grocious of you.

Comment: In several languages for example swedish filial is word in business when a company opens an office or shop in a new city. Surely must be from latin.

Comment: @Michaelyus It is (also) the standard translation of Chinese 孝 _xiào_, one of the main virtues in Confucianist writings and to this day a much-valued trait in young men especially.

Comment: @Hosch250: Hah, that would have been even better.

Comment: Adding context to the answer, filial applies to both sons and daughters because [filius](http://latindictionary.wikidot.com/noun:filius) is the second declension Latin noun for son, and [filia](http://latindictionary.wikidot.com/noun:filia) is the first declension Latin noun for daughter. Latin nouns have various endings to denote gender, number [singular / plural], and case (nominative, genitive, dative, accusative, ablative, locative and vocative). Most first declension Latin nouns are feminine gender, but there are exceptions such as nauta [sailor] that are masculine gender.

Comment: @LenGreski: Quite so! See also this question: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5852/what-is-the-origin-of-the-a-in-words-like-collega-advena

Comment: @mathreadler, that is correct, and whats more interesting is that it is to distinguish from a daughter company which needs to be an Aktiebolag (AB) .

Comment: @ViktorMellgren: *Filiaal* is also used in Dutch in that sense.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps **"progenic"** would also be a suitable candidate. Progenic is the adjective form of [progeny](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/progeny) - which means *"child or offspring"*.

Comment: AFAIK, "progenic"is valid but you wont find it in your day-to-day life.